# Printed Image generated in c# is too big for Zebra ZXP 3

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, printing

I want to print image generated in C# via printer called -  Zebra ZXP 3.
This printer has 86mm x 54 mm card and printing in 300 DPI.

I generated image in this way (badge Height is get from database in mm and then converted in private method to pixel, so I write below value for this variables).

badgeWidth = 1016
badgeHeight = 638

```
 var bitmap = new Bitmap(badgeWidth, badgeHeight);

 bitmap.SetResolution(300, 300);
 SetBackgroundColor(badgeTemplateData, bitmap);
```

Then I have couple method to draw something on bitmap which looks like (some method generate picture, some text, some barcode etc.)

```
private void SetStringElement(string value, Bitmap bitmap, BadgeElement element)
    {
        var left = element.Coordinates.Left;
        var top = element.Coordinates.Top;

        var fontSize = element.ElementStyle.TextSize;

        var textColor = new SolidBrush(element.ElementStyle.TextColor);
        var font = new Font("Arial", fontSize);

        using (Graphics graphic = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            graphic.DrawString(value, font, textColor, left, top);
        }
    }
```

In the end I have method which convert this image to Base64:

```
//This is class which generate Image (look above):
var imageGenerator = new ImageGenerator(badgeTemplate);
var badgeTemplateBitmap = imageGenerator.MapBadgeTemplateToPng(badgeSide);

var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

badgeTemplateBitmap.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Png);

var byteImage = memoryStream.ToArray();

var badgeTemplateBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);

return badgeTemplateBase64;
```

The last step is send this picture to browser, so I calling Ajax which getting above base64:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/Guests/PrintSingleFrontBadgeTemplate",
        type: "post",
        data: { guestTypeId: guestTypeId, guestId: guestId },
        success: function (response) {
            var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=1200,height=800');
            popupWin.document.open();
            popupWin.document.write('<html><head></head><body"><img alt="Embedded Image" src="data:image/png;base64,' + response.frontBadgeTemplate + '" /></html>');
            popupWin.document.close();
            popupWin.print();
            popupWin.close();
        }
    });
```

AND What Can I see? THE Huge image which takes 3 pages... 
As I said my printer printing 86mm x 54mm in 300 dpi. 
To print whole area I need image in 1016px x 638px.
Why my picture is 3 times bigger than I expected?

And the huge surprise is when I download this image and print from windows I have perfectly precision image on one page.